# Feature engineering, ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: python, dataframe, encoding, data-science, feature-engineering

I'm running into a `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` when trying to do encoding for the column `Type`. Here are the codes, not sure which part is wrong.

```
df.head()
```

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
sns.heatmap(df.isnull(), cmap='viridis')
df.isnull().any()
```

[image]

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

[image]

```
df['Rating'] = df['Rating'].fillna(df['Rating'].median())

replaces = [u'\u00AE', u'\u2013', u'\u00C3', u'\u00E3', u'\u00B3', '[', ']', "'"]
for i in replaces:
    df['Current Ver'] = df['Current Ver'].astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.replace(i, ''))

regex = [r'[-+|/:/;(_)@]', r'\s+', r'[A-Za-z]+']
for j in regex:
    df['Current Ver'] = df['Current Ver'].astype(str).apply(lambda x : re.sub(j, '0', x))

df['Current Ver'] = df['Current Ver'].astype(str).apply(lambda x : x.replace('.', ',',1).replace('.', '').replace(',', '.',1)).astype(float)
df['Current Ver'] = df['Current Ver'].fillna(df['Current Ver'].median())
```

[image]

```
i = df[df['Category'] == '1.9'].index
df.loc[i]
```

[image]

```
df = df.drop(i)
```

```
df = df[pd.notnull(df['Last Updated'])]
df = df[pd.notnull(df['Content Rating'])]
```

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['App'] = le.fit_transform(df['App'])
```

```
category_list = df['Category'].unique().tolist() 
category_list = ['cat_' + word for word in category_list]
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['Category'], prefix='cat')], axis=1)
```

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Genres'] = le.fit_transform(df['Genres'])
```

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['Content Rating'] = le.fit_transform(df['Content Rating'])
```

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('$'))
```

```
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('+').replace(',', ''))
```

```
df['Type'] = pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])
```

[image]

Comment: Anyone?........

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a small reproducible example with code which can copied and pasted so people can easier help. Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to map a DataFrame with multiple columns to one column to the original DataFrame.

`pd.get_dummies` returns a DataFrame with a column for each value in the column.

If you want to add those values to the original DataFrame you can use concat.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=['type1', 'type2', 'type3'], columns=['Type'])
dummies_df = pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])
pd.concat([df, dummies_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: No, I will not. That's not how it works. Again, you should provide a small example which you can post in stackoverflow which reproduces the problem you have. I'm pretty sure replacing the line `df['Type'] = pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])` with `df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['Type'])], axis=1))` would solve the issue you have.